# Find the joker in deck of cards

Tags: code-golf

You have a [French deck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_52-card_deck) of cards that **sorted** like this: 2 - 10, Princes, Queens, Kings, Aces.

The deck represented with array of numbers from 1 to 52(included)

Now the dealer is shuffling the deck 3 times and inserting a Joker in a random position of the deck.

The joker represented with the number 0

The idea of shuffling is slicing the array in random position and moving it to the front like in the next examples:

- 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 -> 6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5 // Sliced at 6
- 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 -> 8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 // Sliced at 8

Find the joker position in the array. The challenge is doing this without iterating over the entire deck.

**Winning priority:**

- Best time performance
- Shortest code

Comment: wait, so the challenge is to grep an array for a specific element as fast as possible, but there are no clues where the element could be except the array length is known in advance (thus a linear search has to be applied)? Not to mention the problem is underspecified (how are the cards represented?).

Comment: IOW, the best solution is to code a linear search in C (trivial) and let the compiler unroll the loop fully? Where's the challenge in that?

Comment: "The challenge is doing this without iterating over the entire deck." - uh, no, that is impossible. We _have_ to look at each position except one in the worst case. If we are not allowed to look at them individually, what kinds of group views are possible? If we are to infer anything from the other cards, you need to specify what a shuffle means. Distribute each card of the deck into one of n (2?) stacks, then concatenate the stacks? Split the deck into n stacks and merge them randomly? If the shuffle is fully random, nothing can be inferred from other card positions.

Comment: oh. _That_ kind of shuffle. That isn't really a shuffle but at least now we can apply binary search here.

Comment: it is clear now but still not a good challenge (or at least put in an overcomplicated fashion). Hint: what happens when you shuffle twice?

Comment: so, the joker starts at the front, then you "shuffle" thrice, then we get to look at the array?

Comment: @JanDvorak yep, this is it.

Comment: I assume deletion as soon as you read my answer ;-)

Comment: Considering your recent question history (and associated reputation gains), I strongly suggest you made use of [the sandbox in meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/638/199) before asking in main.

Comment: Cool, did not knew you got sandbox. lol

Comment: @Babibu you were told about it already several times, IIRC.

Comment: @JanDvorak what is IIRC?

Comment: IIRC = If I Remember Correctly. [Urban Dictionary knows that.](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=iirc) [Google knows Urban Dictionary knows that.](https://www.google.com/search?q=iirc)

Comment: Your question was mildly more interesting when you added the joker after shuffling. But even then it was all about golfing a binary search with a few twists.

Comment: @JanDvorak Will it be OK if I revert it to the previous version? Now that I am thinking about it, I like that twist better.

Comment: You should really use the sandbox next time. Maybe you should post a new question, this time through the sandbox? If only to learn the ropes.

Comment: If this is a `code-golf` then why is fastest execution time the main priority ?

Comment: @Babibu, I voted to close because you don't have a single objective criteria for winning here (the "best time performance" goal conflicts with code-golf).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a chameleon question. You can't just change the criteria like that.

Answer (score 6):

## polyglot, constant time, 8 characters

```
52-a[52]
```

The trick is to realise what actually happens when you shuffle the array. Imagine the array as circular. Let us render the array starting at zero with the actual start/end signified with a bar:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 |
```

Now, what actually happens when you shuffle the top three cards to the bottom and re-render:

```
7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 |
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 | 7 8 9
```

Let's shuffle three more cards:

```
0 1 2 3 | 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

The only thing shuffles do is that they rotate the whole array, but don't change the ordering up to rotation.

So, if the array ends with a zero, we want to output the last index. The array has 53 elements, so the last index is 52.

If the array starts with a zero, it ends with its largest value. We want to output zero in this case.

Similarly, if the zero is `n` positions from the end, the last element of the array is `n`. Thus, the position of zero is the last position in the array, minus the value at the last position.

Comment: This is an example to 3 shuffles starting from no shuffles to 3. 0123456789 -> slice at 5 = 5678901234 -> slice at 8 = 8901234567. The solution is 2 in this case

Comment: @Babibu the algorithm works correctly. 9-7=2

Comment: Oh sorry, just now understand it. Cool

Comment: This is really the only possible answer. Though shorter code may be possible.